# Xcode project browser not showing 'GoogleService-Info.plist' even though it's in the directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

So I'm currently building a new app that is to use Firebase as the backend, however I have encountered an issue. I am getting errors with the file: GoogleService-Info.plist' that it is not specified in my project directory, however it is there. What I mean is, in my file browser I can see that the file is indeed there, however when I look at the project browser on Xcode it is not there. I have tried re-opening and whatnot, still didn't help. I hope the images below will help with my issue.
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the file is indeed in the directory but Xcode isn't picking it up! I feel like I am missing a simple step somewhere, but cannot figure it out..

Comment: So drag it from the Finder into Xcode.

Comment: Sorry I am new to xcode, this solved my problem thanks.

Comment: try to drag that plist file again to your project and give only refrence of file instead of copy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though the file exists, xcode still needs to know about it.

Right click your Sprint folder in xcode and select Add files to "Sprint"

then select your plist file to add it to the project.

xCode maintains a project file which contains information about all the files and groups in the project, so you need to add it properly for xcode to know about it. Make sure Sprint is selected as a target when you add the file too.

Answer (score 10):

Simply drag your file from finder to the project.

[image: drag]

Comment: Yep this has worked for me thanks, sorry I am new to xcode and didn't know you could do this.